# New Picture on Tap

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to have an image view and each time you tap on it, it brings up a new picture.
I am using storyboards with Xcode5. Would this also work with the gestures in the iOS SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for gesture recognizer?

Comment: from where it brings up a new picture?

Comment: Yeah something like that. I know that this may seem like a dumb topic but thanks for the help/

Answer (score 2):

Better solution for you is **UIButton**.Gesture adding for **UIImageView** is not a good choice.  You can set a UIButton instead of **UIImageView** first set an image for the UIButton, then you have to add a target for this button tap. Inside that method, you can simply change the image. Sample code is given below:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(SET_FRAME_HERE);
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAME] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonTapHandler {
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ANOTHER_IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```